# Not able to replace AKS server APP ID Key for RBAC

Tags: azure-aks

I need to replace AKS server AAD APP secret key, have tried ARM template increment deployment to achieve this, but failed with following error.

`New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 2:00:42 PM - Error: Code=PropertyChangeNotAllowed; Message=Provisioning of resource(s) for container service
test-aks-emea in resource group test-emea-kubernetes failed. Message: {
"code": "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",
"message": "Changing property 'aadProfile.serverAppSecret' is not allowed.",
"target": "aadProfile.serverAppSecret"
}.`

Is there any other other way we can replace the secret key without redeploying to cluster?

Comment: Any more question? Of if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: @CharlesXu I feel you have miss understood my question, My cluster has RBAC enabled while creating but for some reason server AAD app key got deleted which caused RBAC failure. Hence, we are forced to rotate key . 

now I have  found the way to reset the resetAAD profile with new secret key even with new APP ID. 

 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/resetaadprofile

Comment: Yeah, it seems that I did understand it wrong. I delete the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to reset the resetAAD profile with new secret key using REST API POST method

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/resetaadprofile